# What is the behavior of calling np.random.multinomial many times?

Tags: python, numpy, random, random-seed

When called, `np.random.multinomial` and other sampling functions give a certain number of independent samples from the chosen probability distribution.  For instance,

`np.random.multinomial(20, [1/6.]*6, size=2)`

represents throwing a die 20 times, and then 20 times again.

However, what happens if you call `np.random.multinomial(1, [1/6.]*6, size=1)` a thousand times in succession?  Will I get a thousand independent die rolls, i.e. does `np.random.multinomial` guarantee independent samples and correct distributions between successive calls?  Empirically, it looks like there is some significant correlation between calls.  Is it better to reset `np.random.RandomState` before every call?  This seems wrong somehow.

Comment: Not sure what the problem is. So you want to sample multinomial distribution using multinoulli (aka categorical) by doing multinomial with n=1?  You could sample multinoulli via np.choice as well. Could you show the code and data which lead to the conclusion about correlations?

Comment: Show how you determine the correlation you speak about.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's anecdotal evidence.  Once I ran a more systematic analysis, it seems that successive calls are independent.  To confirm, there's no need to set the seed more than once when using these functions multiple times, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, you could try to do 20 (or any N rolls) by sampling from [multinoulli (categorical) distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_distribution) first and then sum he result.

Along the lines (Python 3.7, x64, Anaconda Windows 10)

```
import numpy as np

def mymultinomial(n: int, p):
    """Hand made multinomial"""

    q = np.random.multinomial(1, p, size=n)

    return np.sum(q, axis=0)
```

Code above called with `mymultinomial(20, 6*[1./6.])` will return one sampled vector of 20 dice throws. You could compare the result with calls to `np.random.multinomial(20, 6*[1./6.])`, my quick tests show no statistical difference.

You could sample via `choice()` as well, could put it to test as well (probably could be done faster vectorized)

```
def mymultinomial(n: int, p):
    """Hand made multinomial, choice"""

    r = np.zeros(len(p), dtype = np.int64)
    for _ in range(0, n):
        q = np.random.choice(len(p), size=1, replace=True, p=p)
        r[q] += 1

    return r
```