# problem with np.random.multinomial and size option in python

Tags: python, numpy, random, size, multinomial

My problem is the following:
I have `N` people choosing between three objects `[1,2,3]` with probabilities `[p_1,p_2,p_3]` such that `p_1+p_2+p_3=1`. Let's call `X_1,X_2,X_3` the counts of the chosen objects in one sample among the `N` people (then, for example, X_1 is the number of people choosing object 1 ).

The vector `X_1,X_2,X_3` follows a multinomial distribution [as in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution).
It is well known that `cov(X_1,X_2)` (covariance between X_1,X_2)`=-N*p_1*p_2`.

I want to verify this covariance formula.
I did two experiments and I got different results. I cannot understand why.

Attempt **A**
I coded (with `p_1=0.4,p_2=0.2,p_3=0.4` and `N=50`):

```
q=np.random.multinomial(50, [0.4,0.2,0.4],size=1000)
df=pd.DataFrame(q,columns=["X_1","X_2","X_3"])
cov_matrix=np.cov([df["X_1"],df["X_2"],df["X_3"]])
```

In my specific case, I got `cov(X_1,X_2)=-4.44586486` : it is very similar to what I was expecting as `-N*p_1*p_2=-50*0.4*0.2=-4`

Attempt **B** (where I sequentially create samples of multinomial draws)
I coded:

```
s=[1]*1000 # 1000 as the size
df["constant"]=s
df["X_1"]= df.apply(lambda x: np.random.multinomial(50, [0.4,0.2,0.4])[0],axis=1)
df["X_2"]= df.apply(lambda x: np.random.multinomial(50, [0.4,0.2,0.4])[1],axis=1)
df["X_3"]= df.apply(lambda x: np.random.multinomial(50, [0.4,0.2,0.4])[2],axis=1)
cov_matrix=np.cov([df["X_1"],df["X_2"],df["X_3"]])
```

In my specific case, I got `cov(X_1,X_2)=-0.087452` : it is very different than what I was expecting (that is 4).

It seems to me the only difference between **A** and **B** is that in **A** size=1000, whereas in **B** I am creating a draw for each row of my dataframe.

Why do I get different results? Which mistakes I am making? There was a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62121098/what-is-the-behavior-of-calling-np-random-multinomial-many-times), but answers are not very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second example, each column is generated independent of the other columns, so each row is no longer a sample from a single *multinomial* distribution. (Note, for example, that the sums of rows are not 50.)  In effect, each column is a binomial distribution that is independent of the other columns.

The second example is equivalent to this (note that I am using the newer random API):

```
In [142]: rng = np.random.default_rng()

In [143]: p = rng.binomial(50, [0.4, 0.2, 0.4], size=(1000, 3))

In [144]: p
Out[144]: 
array([[15, 12, 20],
       [22,  6, 22],
       [17, 12, 17],
       ...,
       [20, 13, 17],
       [27,  9, 24],
       [25,  9, 22]])

In [145]: np.cov(p.T)
Out[145]: 
array([[13.09065465,  0.15038238, -0.22775375],
       [ 0.15038238,  7.85507107, -0.0142022 ],
       [-0.22775375, -0.0142022 , 11.87303203]])
```

Comment: Amazing, good catch! I did not notice that, but why that is the case? Is it a DataFrame feature?

Comment: No, it is a consequence of how you generated the columns in "attempt B". For example, you used `np.random.multinomial(50, [0.4,0.2,0.4])[0]` to generate column `X_1`.  But that throws away columns 1 and 2 of the result of `np.random.multinomial(50, [0.4,0.2,0.4])`.  You need those columns, because the values in a sample from the multinomial distribution are not independent. (If they were, there would be no need for such a distribution!)